# doesn't set text to qlineedit with while loop

Tags: python, pyqt5

My problem is that i'm trying setText from serial data. It has to set text to qlineedit that i've created but it doesn't work.

[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEHuF.png)
[data place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfT0.png)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMainWindow
from ui_1 import Ui_UI as ui
from ui_2 import Ui_confWindow
from time import sleep

from serialData import serial_reader as sr 
class main2(QMainWindow,sr):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.collect = sr()
        self.ui=ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.txtAlt = self.ui.txtAlt
        self.ui.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.startDataWriting)

    def startDataWriting(self):
        number = 0
        while True:
            self.txtAlt.setText(str(number))
            number+=1
            sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    calistir = main2()
    calistir.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what serial data?

Comment: it is getting data from serial port through arduino